# How to solve linux error - "cannot find -lGL"?

Tags: c++, linux, qt, opengl

I have deepin os and trying to build Qt desktop app but I'm getting this error: cannot find -lGL. What does it mean and how to fix it?

Comment: Y'all got `libgl1-mesa-dev` (which provides `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so`) installed?

Comment: http://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-project-qmake-libraries.html

Comment: @genpfault Thank you very much. Solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure `libgl1-mesa-dev` (which provides `/usr/lib/<multiarch name>/libGL.so`) is installed.

The `-l<library name>` switch tells GCC to search its library paths for `lib<library name>.so` and link against it.